# Conditional compile in .aspx files

Tags: asp.net

I need the the .ASPX file to behave differently based on a conditional compilation symbol.

Let's say as an easy example:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" (...) %>
<% #ifdef DEBUG %>
     <asp:SomeDebugControlHere runat="server"/>
     .. well .. a LOT of code here
<% #else %>
    <asp:SomeReleaseControlHere runat="server"/>
    .. and a LOT of other code here
<% #endif %>
```

**Later Edit**: a few more clarifications. The problem is that the class *SomeDebugControlHere* is not even defined in the release build (it's way more complicated in real-life, but bear with this example). So in the page.aspx.designer.cs I need to get this in the debug build:

```
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.SomeDebugControlHere myControl
```

and this in the release build: (and never both)

```
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.SomeReleaseControlHere myControl
```

Obviously I need the mark-up in the ASPX file to be different, but I need the designer.cs file to be modified as well to incorporate the new objects/classes.

I'm just hoping somebody knows of a clever way of doing this either by some control inheritance, anything that would allow me to specify different control classes depending on compilation build settings.

Comment: In your example code you show #ifdef DEBUG  --  Note that C# requires this to be #if DEBUG.  I think that's the true problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a difference when compiling with the compilation symbols depending on where you declare them: As a project property, using a @Page directive or in web.config.

Only the symbols defined in **web.config** seem to be working in the .aspx files.

```
<compiler
      language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
      compilerOptions="/d:MY_CONSTANT"
      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, 
        System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
```

Found some info on this [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx) and [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/09/24/more-on-conditional-compilation-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: I have a project where the symbols are also working in the `<%@ Page ...%>` directive. In the [2nd article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/09/24/more-on-conditional-compilation-in-asp-net.aspx) you've mentioned it is described that the settings are **not additive** which means that if you're specifying `CompilerOptions="/d:MY_CONSTANT"` in the @Page directive, it **overrides** the /d flag you have specified in the web.config.

Answer (score 8):

Your if just needs a tweak, should be:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
```

If you want it to behave like a set of C# code would.

Comment: Well, that's the point.. this does not work :-( . I need the code-behind file to change based on this symbol. And it does not (VS2008 and/or VS2010)

Comment: @Radu094 - How do you mean?  Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do in the code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

I think to some extent the answer is in the auto-generated comments in the designer file:

```
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.SomeDebugControlHere myControl
```

You should probably move the declaration of these controls to your code-behind file, and wrap them in matching `#ifdef` statements.